# How to make the entity key value user-assigned

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first, unit-of-work

I'm retrieving data from another database that has already created unique IDs for each "beer" entity. However, when I assign the unique key value from the remote database to a new "beer" object, it gets replaced as soon as the object is inserted into the database.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using BeerRecommender.Models.ViewModels;

namespace BeerRecommender.Models
{
    public class Beer
    {
        public Beer()
        {
            Created = DateTime.Now;
            Updated = DateTime.Now;
        }

    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public Brewery Brewery { get; set; }

    public DateTime Created { get; set; }

    public DateTime Updated { get; set; }

    public ICollection<City> Cities { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

    public Style Style { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I'm using the [UnitOfWork](http://www.asp.net/entity-framework/tutorials/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) pattern.

```
UnitOfWork.BeerRepository.Insert(beer);
UnitOfWork.Save();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already discovered, EF will generate values for `int` primary keys. To fine tune this behavior you need to mark your key with the [DatabaseGenerated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.databasegeneratedattribute%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) attribute (or you can also configure this with the the [fluent api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh134698)'s [HasDatabaseGeneratedOption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.configuration.primitivepropertyconfiguration.hasdatabasegeneratedoption%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) method):

```
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
```